# How to add local dependency to vendor when using go mod

Tags: go, vendor, go-modules

Before I used `go dep`, but now office ensure the official tool is `go mod`.

When I use `go dep`, I can add local dependency packages to vendor and **`ignored`** in `Gopkg.toml` to ignore search the package from repo. I can execute `go dep update` normally.

Now I use `go mod`, I also add local dependence package to vendor and add it `exclude` in `go.mod`. But when i execute `go mod tidy`, it remove the package even though my project exist `import xxx`.

What did i do:

1. create new project
2. execute go mod init
3. modify go.mod **`exclude privaterepo.com/bb/bb`**
4. copy my local module to vendor because the local module is on a private repo which not support https.
5. now the vendor just like:

   > `vendor
   >   |-github.com/aa/aa
   >   |-privaterepo.com/bb/bb`
6. import "privaterepo.com/bb/bb"
7. execute go build -mod vendor
8. than i got error **"cannot find module for path privaterepo.com/bb/bb"**
   9 always try with replace, but it also not work

So, what should I do to add **local package** to vendor and avoid `go mod` remove it?

Comment: Did you try `go mod vendor`?

Comment: What is a "local package"? All packages are equal.

Comment: @ttomalak if i didn't execute `go mod vendor`, it wouldn't create the vendor folder.

Comment: @Volker I means the package in my private repo which not support https both and need auth. So the only way is that i git clone use ssh than i copy the package to vendor. Such as vendor/xxx.com/xxx/xx.

Comment: Okay, got that. But I still do not understand the problem. Can you describe the problem more clearly?

Comment: @Volker I had append my description.

Answer (score 12):

> So, what should I do to add local package to vendor and avoid go mod remove it?

Well, I think you cannot do this. This is not how it works. `go mod vendor` *manages* your vendor folder.

Instead of `exclude`ing you package from go.mod you should add a `replace` directive to instruct the go tool to look up the package not from privaterepo.com but from the local filesystem. Quoting from https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive

> replace also can be used to inform the go tooling of the relative or absolute on-disk location of modules in a multi-module project, such as:
>
> ```
>    replace example.com/project/foo => ../foo
> ```

So in your case: Do not try to manually put privaterepo.com/bb/bb in vendor, but have it somewhere outside the current project and use

```
replace privaterepo.com/bb/bb => ../bb
```

And let `go mod` copy this stuff from the filesystem to your vendor.

Comment: I had read the modules wiki, and i known i can copy **privaterepo.com/bb/bb** to outside vendor folder, also if i do this i won't need to add `replace privaterepo.com/bb/bb => ../bb`  in the go.mod.

But what's the mean of `exclude`, when should i use `exclude`?

I prefer manager my private repo in vendor just like other public repo.

Comment: @yanyandenuonuo `exclude` is for excluding a specific _version_ of a module if you know that this version is broken/doesn't work with our code. IN this case you can mark this version as excluded an go will not select this version during version selection. For the second part: If you manage your build with modules and `go mod` than you must adopt your workflow to go mod.

Comment: May be i should ask the question at golang issue. I don't think `exclude` is for excluding a specific version because `require` already declare the version. Anyway, thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @yanyandenuonuo exclude is for excluding a single version from the set of possibles and require is to select a single fixed version. Have a second look at the documentation if unsure.

Comment: Got it, but i don't think this is right things about `exclude` and i had create a issue about this. Thank you once again.